# Проблема реализации рекурсии. Задание в описании. Язык - С++

Tags: c++, функции, рекурсия

Задание элементарное, но прошу не смеяться и не унижать.

> **Дана последовательность из N чисел Х1, Х2, … , ХN. Вычислить значение выражения: Хn(Хn+Xn-1)(Хn+Xn-1+Xn-2)(Хn+Xn-1+Xn2+Xn-3) ...
> (Хn+Xn-1+Xn-2+...+X1). Массив не использовать.**

В случае моей программы, рекурсивная функция постоянно возвращает значение последнего введённого аргумента, в итоге, например, при вводe 3 программа выводит значение 3 умножить на 6 умножить на 9, а не 3 умножить на 5 умножить на 6. Как возможно это исправить? Код приведён.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;
static int sum = 0;
static int rez = 1;
int a;

int function(int nn)
{
    if (nn == 0)
        return 0;
    else if (nn > 0) {
        cin >> a;
        sum = function(nn - 1) + a;
        rez = rez * sum;
        return sum;
    }
}

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "RUS");

    int n;

    cout << "Введите количество цифр: " << endl;

    cin >> n;

    function(n);
    cout << rez;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Задача была исправлена следующим кодом:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;
static int rez = 1;

int function(int nn)
{   int a;
    int sum = 0;
    if (nn == 0)
        return 0;
    else if (nn > 0)
    {
        cin >> a;
        sum = a + function(nn - 1);
        rez = rez * sum;
        return sum;
    }
}

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "RUS");

    int n;

    cout << "Введите количество цифр: " << endl;

    cin >> n;

    function(n);
    cout << rez;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Вероятно, сложность представляет то, что суммирование ведётся в обратном порядке. Рекурсивная функция должна на каждом уровне иметь и сумму значений от **последующего** ввода, и произведение сумм **последующих** вводов. Для возврата пары параметров используем результат функции и ссылочную переменную (наверное, на текущем уровне обучения не стоит использовать возврат пары/тупля). Для того, чтобы при вызове из main не заводить переменную для суммирования, введём функцию-прокладку.

```
int func(int n, int &summ) {
    int x;
    cin >> x;

    if (n == 1)
        return summ = x; 

    int prod = func(n - 1, summ);
    summ += x;
    return summ * prod;
}

int f(int n) {
    int s = 0;
    return func(n, s);
}
int main()
{
    cout << f(3); 
}
```

Проверяем - для n=3 и ввода 5,2,3 получаем `150 = 3*(3+2)*(3+2+5)`

P.S. Аналогичного результата можно добиться без рекурсии при использовании (явного) стека, но это может расцениваться как нарушение условия "Массив не использовать"

Comment: Не ясно требование задачи, но может вы правы.

Comment: @AR Hovsepyan Я взял произвольные числа. На всякий случай, чтобы не было сомнений, дал другой пример.

Comment: это понятно, но я к тому, что если задана последовательность, то как она вообще задана(что передать функции)?  И  для чего эта рекурсия, если просто можно поэлементно выполнить операции?...

Comment: @AR Hovsepyan Если бы был массив (или другой способ сохранения вводимых данных), то мы бы легко обошли его с конца и получили результат согласно формуле. Но в том-то и дело, что при условии "Массив не использовать" последовательность - некий вид потока, в данном случае ввод из консоли, и не так-то просто посчитать сначала для последних введённых данных, потом ближе и ближе к началу.

Comment: согласен,  логика на вашей стороне, а я был не внимателен при чтении вопроса. Спасибо за  отзыв

Comment: @Mbo Всеравно нет необходимости в рекурсии или массиве, сложения и умножения можно считать в обоих направлениях, и тогда задача опять сводится к циклу :) Хоть для такого решения и нужно подумать а не просто передрать формулу :)

Comment: @Владимир Клыков Где вы возьмёте значения для обратного прохода цикла?

Comment: Разверну формулу для подсчета с начала а не с хвоста, вроде математика такое позволяет :)

Comment: @Владимир Клыков Хм.. Или мы задачу по-разному поняли, или вы видите какой-то не сильно сложный способ, который я не углядел.

Comment: По разному поняли, соглашусь с вами что это достаточно сложно, но не невозможно, надо поковырять на досуге, даже интересно стало выйдет или нет

Answer (score 0):

Для решения задачи не нужны ни массивы ни рекурсия, достаточно одного цикла.

```
i := 3
sum := 0
res := 1
for ; i > 0; i-- {
    sum = sum + i
    res = res * sum
}
```

*(ps. да простят меня за синтаксис, но под рукой был golang)*

Comment: Нужно использовать именно рекурсивную функцию)

Comment: В чем сложность? алгоритм перед вами, сделать из него рекурсию - 2 секунды дела

Comment: Минус от меня. X_i не равно i.

Comment: @Harry Уже давно выяснили что алгоритм не тот :) сбили с толку примеры изначальные ;)